# MultipleFileField wtforms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, multiple-file-upload

```
class AddProductForm(FlaskForm):
    product_pictures = MultipleFileField('Pictures')
    submit = SubmitField('Add Pictures')

    def product_add_pics():
        form = AddProductForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.product_pictures.data:
                for picture_upload in form.product_pictures.data:
                    print(type(picture_upload))
```

form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.product_pictures.label() }}
    {{ form.product_pictures(class="form-control-file") }}
    {% if form.product_pictures.errors %}
        {% for error in form.product_pictures.errors %}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

I always got type as string. How can I get the binary files? I use MultipleFileField from the wtforms.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FileField) for the `FileField` class specifically says the following about handling file contents:

> By default, the value will be the filename sent in the form data.
> WTForms does not deal with frameworks’ file handling capabilities.

This same thing applies to the `MultipleFileField` class as well.

What this means is that you will have to ask `flask` for those files. And, the quickest way to do that is to use the `request.files` for the request you are handling.

In sum, you will need to rewrite your `product_add_pics` function to grab the files from the `request` object, as follows:

```
from flask import request



def product_add_pics():
    form = AddProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pics = request.files.getlist(form.product_pictures.name)
        if pics:
            for picture_upload in pics:
                picture_contents = picture_upload.stream.read()
                print(type(picture_contents))
                # Do everything else you wish to do with the contents
```

You'll notice the usage of `request.files.getlist` here. This is important since you're using a `MultipleFielField` class to accept multiple files. Using `.getlist` allows you to retrieve all the files the end user selected from their machine.

And finally, to get the bytes contained in each file, you will need to get the `stream` of each file and `read` it. That should yield the bytes you're looking for.

I hope this proves useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I spent four hours banging my head against the wall trying to find a solution and finally figured it out with the help of an error code. MultiFileField will return the filenames as a string unless you specify the proper encoding in your form. simply add:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to the HTML form tag and the original code will return

```
<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'>
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files in a form you need to add the enctype as show below

```
<div class="form-group" method="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ form.product_pictures.label() }}
{{ form.product_pictures(class="form-control-file") }}
{% if form.product_pictures.errors %}
    {% for error in form.product_pictures.errors %}
        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I tried this and it solved solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).