# Flask WTForms MultipleFileField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to save multiple files through WTForm. Since there is no documentation on how you need to use MultipleFileField I looked on SO and came accross multiple answers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890136/how-to-upload-multiple-files-with-flask-wtf/54011475#54011475) one looked promising but it doesn't work. The `file` variable is a string and thus the code doesn't work.

```
class CreatePostForm(FlaskForm):
    files = MultipleFileField('Upload files', validators={DataRequired()})
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Submit'))
```

```
@app.route('/create_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_post():
    form = CreatePostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        files_filenames = []
        for file in form.files.data:
            file_filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_filename))
            files_filenames.append(file_filename)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Does your forrm have the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute ?

Comment: It did not, I assumed it would add that automatically when using the MultipleFileField in the form.

Comment: I am not sure about that, WTF can create the form fields as necessary but you should still add the <form> tags in your page. - see: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WTF/form.html (this is for the Flask version but should be equally relevant). If in doubt, look at the resulting HTML source code in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the MultipleFileField doesn't add the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the html form. You have to do this manually to make this work.

So the above code works with this html page.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</form>
```