# Saving multiple files through flask and wtforms MultipleFileField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to get and save several files from request in Flask using MultipleFileField. But the problem is that I can't iterate through it. What I mean:
Form class

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    user_id = IntegerField('user_id', validators=[DataRequired()])
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = StringField('description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    category_id = IntegerField('category_id', validators=[DataRequired()])
    date_of_purchase = DateField('date_of_purchase', validators=[DataRequired()])
    guarantee_period = IntegerField('guarantee_period', validators=[DataRequired()])
    files = MultipleFileField('files')
```

And view code:

```
form = TestForm()
...
files = form.files
for file in files:
   with open(path.join('some_path', file.filename), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file.read())
```

I get this massive in request:

```
["<_io.BufferedReader name='1.jpg'>", "<_io.BufferedReader name='2.jpg'>"]
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

So it converts `io.BufferedReader` to `str`. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I haven't used `MultipleFileField` but with `FileField` all you need to do is `form.file.data.save(path)`. Does that work in this case (e.g. inside your loop just do a `file.data.save(path)` or something similar)?

Comment: @noslenkwah no, it doesn't work the same. I also tried it.

Comment: @noslenkwah in this case `form.file.data` returns the list with `io.BufferedReader` converted to string

Comment: just names of the class

Comment: I tried it out. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733307/4032503)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'file' is a string, slice it before the with statement and save to a filename variable, then include just 'filename' inside the with statement. Something like:

```
form = TestForm()
...
files = form.files.data
for file in files:
   with open(path.join('some_path', file), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file.read())
```

Comment: It doesn't help( The erorr is `TypeError: 'MultipleFileField' object is not iterable`

Comment: I just edited the answer, .data brings all content from the form as a list, this might be what you need

Comment: Hm, I tried your code again today in the morning and it works great... I just can't imagine what was the problem yesterday)